# Gsub, extract certain amount of digits

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Sorry if there was an answer to my question somewhere in here. Unfortunately I could not find it.

I have a string having a following form "ANNNNNNN.tif" where A is just a letter and N is a digit. There are 7 digits in a row.

```
new <- c("A2000001.tif" ,"A2000002.tif", "A2000003.tif", "A2000004.tif", "A2000005.tif", "A2000006.tif")
```

I want to get year and month value out of it. the first 4 digits represent year and last 2 - month. E.g. I wrote this to get a year value

```
year1 <- gsub("([0-9]){3,4}?.*$", "", new)
year <- as.numeric(gsub("A", "", year1))
```

But I suppose it could be written shorter and I still struggle to get a month value.

UPD: And I wrote this to get a month.

```
month1 <- gsub("^*.([0-9]){6,7}?", "\\1", new)
month <- as.numeric(gsub(".tif", "", month1))
```

But still for learning purposes I would like to know how to do it in a better way.

Comment: Are trying to create the string or extract the digits?  Please clarify.

Comment: I have a name of the files: "A2000001.tif" "A2000002.tif" "A2000003.tif" "A2000004.tif" "A2000005.tif" "A2000006.tif" etc. I want to get out of it year and month of an image. So the first 4 digits represent year and the last 2 month.

Comment: `read.fwf(textConnection(new), widths = c(1, 4, 3), col.names = c('letter', 'year', 'month'))`.. er, not sure what the extra 0 is, if this needs to be avoided, you can put it in a separate column `read.fwf(textConnection(new), widths = c(1, 4, 1, 2), col.names = c('l', 'y', 'x', 'm'))`

Comment: If you want to extract the actual date, `as.Date(sub('.*(\\d{4}).(\\d{2}).*', '\\1-\\2-01', new))` or `zoo::as.yearmon(new, 'A%Y0%m')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some base options:

```
new <- c("A2000001.tif" ,"A2000002.tif", "A2000003.tif",
         "A2000004.tif", "A2000005.tif", "A2000006.tif")
```

Assuming they are always at the same positions within the strings:

```
as.integer(substr(new, 2, 5))
# [1] 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
as.integer(substr(new, 7, 8))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

A little more adaptive, assuming they always either follow a non-number (year) or precede a dot (month):

```
as.integer(sub("^[^0-9]([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", new))
# [1] 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
as.integer(sub(".*([0-9]{2})\\..*", "\\1", new))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Extract all numbers and do some fancy-math on them:

```
x <- as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", new))
x %/% 1000
# [1] 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
x %% 100
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Uber-powerful regular-expression extraction (https://xkcd.com/1171/):

```
lapply(
  regmatches(new,
             gregexpr("(?<![0-9])[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}(?![0-9])", new, perl = TRUE)),
  as.integer
)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2000    1
# [[2]]
# [1] 2000    2
# [[3]]
# [1] 2000    3
# [[4]]
# [1] 2000    4
# [[5]]
# [1] 2000    5
# [[6]]
# [1] 2000    6
```

(Though this last one is a list of vectors, slightly different format for your consumption.)

Comment: Thank you, r2evans! That is really detailed response!

Answer (score 2):

`tidyr` has very powerful `separate` that works well on data frames/data tables,

```
new <- c("A2000001.tif" ,"A2000002.tif", "A2000003.tif", "A2000004.tif", "A2000005.tif", "A2000006.tif")

library(tidyr)

df <- as.data.frame(new) %>%
  separate(new, into = c("letter", "year", "extra", "month", "extension"), sep=c(1,5,6,8), remove = FALSE) %>%
  select(-extra, -extension)

df         

#            new letter year month
# 1 A2000001.tif      A 2000    01
# 2 A2000002.tif      A 2000    02
# 3 A2000003.tif      A 2000    03
# 4 A2000004.tif      A 2000    04
# 5 A2000005.tif      A 2000    05
# 6 A2000006.tif      A 2000    06
```

The following is a typical approach with `gsub` in base R . In each case match as much of the leading part of the string, match the interesting part in capturing parentheses, the match the rest. Replace with "\\1" to indicate the captured value

```
new <- c("A2000001.tif" ,"A2000002.tif", "A2000003.tif", "A2000004.tif", "A2000005.tif", "A2000006.tif")
letter <- gsub("(.).*", "\\1", new)
year <- as.numeric(gsub(".(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", new))
month <- as.numeric(gsub(".\\d{4}.(\\d{2}).+", "\\1", new))
```

Comment: Thank you, epi99! Looks handy!